# Sympy real roots

Tags: python, sympy

Anyone know how the real_roots function works in sympy? Because on the official page I don't find how sympy evaluates the solution. In particular, I am only interested in the solution of a polynomial function

Comment: Your question is unclear to me. Are you asking how to _use_ the `real_roots` function, or are you asking what algorithms it's using under the hood?

Comment: I'm asking about the algorithms

Answer (score 2):

The `real_roots` function supports finding the real roots of an univariate polynomial with rational coefficients e.g.:

```
In [12]: real_roots(x**2 - 1)
Out[12]: [-1, 1]

In [13]: real_roots(x**2 + 1)
Out[13]: []
```

Internally this is done in several stages:

1. The polynomial can be completely factorised over the rationals into irreducibles.
2. For each irreducible expressions for the roots are computed as either rational, radical or `CRootOf`.
3. Root isolation algorithms are used to identify which of those roots is real.

Note that step 1 immediately identifies all rational roots since they are reduced to linear factors. In step 2 the cubic and quartic formulas are not used but the quadratic formula is and decomposition and other techniques are possibly tried (not sure). You can use the `roots` function for the cubic and quartic formulas but they usually produce excessively complicated output. Anything not handled becomes `CRootOf`.

In step 3 the implementation can work for `CRootOf` meaning that it can also work for quintics and higher degree polynomials (it is not limited by Abel-Ruffini):

```
In [6]: [r] = real_roots(x**5 - x - 1)

In [7]: r
Out[7]: 
       ⎛ 5           ⎞
CRootOf⎝x  - x - 1, 0⎠

In [8]: r.evalf()
Out[8]: 1.16730397826142
```

The root isolation code is here:
https://github.com/sympy/sympy/blob/01a5776b9feaf01d06c94165ccebe4ac4b617a7b/sympy/polys/rootisolation.py

That code implements some fairly complex algorithms that are apparently quite fast but the implementation in sympy is very slow for higher degree polynomials. I am not sure if those algorithms are optimal for something like univariate polynomials or whether the implementation is just not well optimised. I think that an implementation based on the interval-Newton method could be much faster:

https://github.com/sympy/sympy/issues/19164